# If-statement in while loop not reading last output from if-statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to put the sum of two numbers from list x of which the division by 20 of that sum is not possible into list z. My code does not comply with the rule that only a combination of two numbers from list x can be used. So, for instance, 35 is not valid since it can't be formed by adding two numbers from list x. However, it still occurs in the result of list z.

Also, I'm adding up 'target' by 5 since 5 is the lowest number in list x.

What am I doing wrong?

```
x = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
target = 5
combi=0
max = x[0]+x[1]
z = []
while target <= max:
    for i in x:
        if i < target:
            pair = target - i
            if pair in x:
                combi = 1
    if combi == 1 and target % 20 != 0:
        z.append(target)
    target += 5
print(z)
```

Given output: [10, 15, 25, 30, 35, 45, 50, 55, 65, 70, 75, 85, 90, 95, 105, 110, 115, 125, 130, 135, 145, 150, 155, 165, 170, 175, 185, 190, 195, 205, 210, 215, 225, 230, 235, 245, 250, 255, 265, 270, 275, 285, 290, 295]

Desired output: [10, 15, 25, 30, 55, 70, 105, 110, 150, 205, 210, 250]

Comment: You never reset `combi` to 0. The `combi = 0` assignment should be moved inside the `while` loop

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never reset the "combi" variable. Here is your fixed code

```
x = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
target = 5
combi=0
max = x[0]+x[1]
z = []
while target <= max:
    for i in x:
        if i < target:
            pair = target - i
            if pair in x:
                combi = 1
    if combi == 1 and target % 20 != 0:
        z.append(target)
    target += 5
    combi = 0
print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
x = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
z = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
        sum=x[i]+x[j]
        if sum%20!=0:
            z.append(sum)
z.reverse()
print(z)
```

your desired output:

output:
[15, 25, 30, 55, 70, 105, 110, 150, 205, 210, 250]

Comment: i think 10 is not valid as output

Comment: because 10 is not created by adding two numbers

Comment: Thanks, but 10 = 5+5.

Comment: in list x has only one 5 , so another 5 comes from?